# How to change Camera sensor orientation using camera2 API?

Tags: android

Because I use AutoFitSurfaceView, so I need to use Android Camera2 API.
I use AutoFitSurfaceView as Preview of live streaming,but AutoFitSurfaceView strech images.

This is officeal solution.
But I don't know how to get

```
surfaceRotationDegrees
previewWidth 
previewHeight
```

These three variables

https://developer.android.com/training/camera2/camera-preview#kotlin

```
override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
    val width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)
    val height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec)

    val relativeRotation = computeRelativeRotation(characteristics, surfaceRotationDegrees)

    if (previewWidth > 0f && previewHeight > 0f) {
        /* Scale factor required to scale the preview to its original size on the x-axis. */
        val scaleX =
            if (relativeRotation % 180 == 0) {
                width.toFloat() / previewWidth
            } else {
                width.toFloat() / previewHeight
            }
        /* Scale factor required to scale the preview to its original size on the y-axis. */
        val scaleY =
            if (relativeRotation % 180 == 0) {
                height.toFloat() / previewHeight
            } else {
                height.toFloat() / previewWidth
            }

        /* Scale factor required to fit the preview to the SurfaceView size. */
        val finalScale = min(scaleX, scaleY)

        setScaleX(1 / scaleX * finalScale)
        setScaleY(1 / scaleY * finalScale)
    }
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height)
}
```

Comment: I think you can get the preview width and height just from the view doing getWidth and getHeight, and then you can get the surfaceRotationDegreees from the CameraCharacteristics using 
CameraCharacteristics.get(LENS_POSE_ROTATION) maybe?

Comment: @Z3R0 Your answer seems not work,but thanks.

Comment: Sorry I'm not trying the code, which part doesn't work the degrees or the width/height?